# floating divs jumps below each other when minimize browser window

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs in my page header.First div is faculty logo, second div is website title and third div is university logo.

Entire header has CSS:

```
height: 55px;
width:auto;
```

and background color.

First div has:

```
#header .logoUt {
  width:285px;
  height:55px;
  float:left;
  background:url(images/Drawing1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-position:left center; }
```

Same for second div: fixed width and float left and a text.

Third div:

```
#header .logoEtti {
  width:285px;
  height:55px;
  float:right;
  background:url(images/Drawing1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-position:left center; }
```

Question is: How can I do when I minimize browser windows those div to not jump below each other. Sorry for my bad english.

P.S. I can't set a fixed width for entire header because I want the header background to be streched from left to right in entire page with height 55px.

Answer (score 4):

You could set a `min-width` for the entire header:

```
#header {min-width: 855px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to not use floats but positioning.

Try this:

Give the header `position:relative`

Give all the 3 divs inside `position: absolute`

Use `top:0;left:0` for the first div

Use `top:0;right:0` for the last one

And for the middle one give the correct `px` value for left: